# If given the choice, should I be passing data by passing through params or by connecting through the Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React and Redux and it's my first project in React overall.  As of now I have a bunch of Components that all "get" and "set" the global data through Redux.  So basically every component has this :

```
this.props.actions.UseInfo(this.props.commonData);


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    commonData: state.something.commonData
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(someActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)
```

Now I noticed in React without Redux.. you have to structure your app to pass your data through parameters like

```
<SomeComponent someParam={this.commonData} />
<SomeComponent someParam={this.commonData} />
```

Is there any reason I should take the time to restructure my app to pass more information through parameters and use the Redux actions/reducers less unless if needed?

It seems like structuring to combine the best of both worlds .. maybe having the main components connect to the store and then pass that information down to it's sub components is probably the most ideal, but is there any reason why i "should" be doing that over just connecting everything through the store?

At the end of the day I feel like it's accomplishing the same thing.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.xchpeakga) by Dan Abramov, the creator of Redux.

It says, basically, that container components get data via `connect`, and presentational components get data via `props`.

Comment: i see.  i kinda knew that already, but I feel like all my components are "containers" and thus they all need to connect to the store.  if that's true I guess I dont need to restructure?

i'm wondering if i'm designing it incorrectly if i have no presentational components (creating a pretty data heavy one page app with no links).

Comment: reading the article and some of the articles that it linked as well, giving me some good insight.  particularly this one https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.qhird3rnq

ty

Comment: You may want to look at pieces of your application and question whether there is no room for reusable, dumb components (components that are not state-aware).  I'm sure you'll find more than a few opportunities for components that accept and present data.  Such components are easier to unit test.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of advantages to splitting out presentational or "dumb" components that simply react to their props. Namely, reusability and centralization (you know where to look for things, dumb components rarely require much maintenance).

In the real world it's never black and white, of course. Do the best you can but don't obsess over it, just do what makes sense for your app. Without knowing more about the hierarchy of your project, it's hard to know if you have a problem or maybe just a simple app and it doesn't make much difference. In general I would say watch out for nested "smart" components.

Comment: ty for your insight